# Getting Rust in QNX

Tags: qnx, rust

I saw this article on the blackberry site
https://blogs.blackberry.com/en/2023/02/this-is-the-kind-of-rust-the-automotive-industry-needs

Do anyone know if this is available yet? Even as a preview package or similar?

I would very much like to try it out. So if it is possible to download and install in a QNX 7.x or CAR3 environment, I would be very happy if someone could give me some pointers how to do that.